# Custom Swing Component and updating JScrollPane scrollbars

Tags: java, swing, custom-controls

I have created a custom JComponent which draws text in paintComponent. Putting it in a ScrollPane I want to automatically display the scollbars when the appended text exceeds the viewport. When I resize the whole frame the scrollbars are updated correctly. But I would like to do it programmatically. I tried several #validate() and #invalidate() calls, but to no avail.

How do I update the scrollbars of a scrollpane with a custom component as client?

I created a simpified runnable example to show what I mean:

```java
package swingscroll;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SwingScroll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame(SwingScroll.class.getSimpleName());
        final JComponent myComponent = new JComponent() {
            private Dimension preferredSize;

            @Override
            public void setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize) {
                super.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
                this.preferredSize = preferredSize;
            }


            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return this.preferredSize;
            }

        };
        myComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380, 50));

        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myComponent);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // simulate the internal change of preferredSize in myComponent
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SwingScroll.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // this should trigger the scrollbar right?
                        myComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380, 1000));
                        // TODO insert code to update scrollbars
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I have created a custom JComponent which draws text.."*  What does the custom code do (*besides* fail) that cannot be done in a `JLabel`, `JTextField`, `JTextArea`, `JEditorPane` etc.?

Comment: It allows draggable vertical rulers (with right aligned text) and a more or less intelligent text selection. I am not really sure it can't be done using a JTextComponent or similar. Replacing the custom component by a jlabel and calling #setText behaves correctly. But all I see in #setText is revalidate and repaint. When I add revalidate and repaint in my simple example the scrollbars still don't get updated. I can't follow the code what else is necessary. What does JLabel do to get the scrollbars to update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// TODO insert code to update scrollbars
myComponent.revalidate();
```

just saw your comment:

> When I add revalidate and repaint in my simple example the scrollbars still don't get updated.

Worksforme - though the problem with your example here is that the scrollbars are always showing, so it appears like nothing happens. Adjusting sizes so that there's really no vertical scrollbar initially and then update to a height that must show the bars is just fine.

BTW: I assume that the setPref in the example is just for demonstrating, *not* in production code.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Yes the setPref stuff is demo only. I now added revalidate() at the end of my paintComponent() method of my custom component, which solved my problem. Somehow I get the feeling that I am doing it wrong. paintComponent renders the text and caches the rectangles for each text so that getPreferredSize can use these cached rects to compute the needed height of the whole component. Should it be done otherwise?

Comment: your feeling is correct - **never-ever** do change the state of the component while painting. Instead, change the state and then call repaint/revalidate as needed